# Use "windows(width=x,height=y)" function with built-in graphic device in StatEt?

Tags: eclipse, r, graphics, plot, statet

I'm working with StatEt in Eclipse. The built-in 
graphic device of StatEt generally works very well 
and is of big use (big thanks to the developpers).
But when I start a plot with the windows() function 
to set the size (width & height) of the new window,
this window will be opened by R outside StatEt &
R crashes.
Anybody an idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Okidoki ;) Problem gelöst!!
dev.new() anstatt windows()
benutzen.

Comment: Sounds like a problem that should be posed on their dedicated mailing list. Guess you have implied you are on a Windoze device, but you really should give a more complete description of your setup when you do so.

Comment: @te_ar put that as an answer and accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved: Use `dev.new()` instead of `windows()` !